# Admin plugin, how can I output a different content-type?

Tags: plugins, admin

I'm creating a plugin with an admin page that needs to:

- stream a file for download (set content-type & other headers)
- display HTML without the admin menu etc

In both of these cases the 'pages' **must** be accessible only to logged in administrators. So far I've found one way to accomplish both of these, by including wp-blog-header.php in a php file, checking the user is an admin and doing things myself from then on, as below.

```
require('../../../wp-blog-header.php');

if (!current_user_can('administrator'))
{
    wp_die( __('You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.') );
} 

...set headers & stream file
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Is there any reason I shouldn't do it this way?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

I've done this two ways:

1) - a csv export function - detect that special content type handling is required BEFORE wp outputs anything.

```
add_action ('plugins_loaded',           'amr_meta_handle_csv');

function amr_meta_handle_csv ($csv, $suffix='csv') {
// chcek if there is a csv request on this page BEFORE we do anything else ?
if (( isset ($_POST['csv']) )) {
// do some stuff
      to_csv ($csv, $suffix)
}
}


function to_csv ($csv, $suffix) {
/* create a csv file for download */
    if (!isset($suffix)) $suffix = 'csv';
    $file = 'userlist-'.date('YmdHis').'.'.$suffix;
    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
    header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file");
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Expires: 0");
    echo $csv;
    exit(0);   /* Terminate the current script sucessfully */
}
```

Another way was more feed oriented, but same principle, except wp does the special handling detection (checks for ?feed=ics or ).  Put the add_feed code in an init action.

```
add_feed('ics', 'ical_feed');
```

function 'ical_feed' then does the whole header etc.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at the WordPress HTTP API.
http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3.2/wp-includes/http.php

As far as the rest of plugin development. Read the [plugin API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API) or about [writing a plugin](http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin).

Comment: The HTTP API is for _fetching external resources,_ not for sending pages. And the asker obviously knows already the plugin basics.